# RunTimeError in merge sort function using python

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to write a merge sort function using python 2 but i get a RunTimeError

> Input: unsorted list (ex:[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
>
> Output: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

My code is shown below:

```
lst = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
def mergesort(array):
if len(array) == 1:
    return array
left = []
right = []
for i in array:
    if i <= len(array)/2:
        left.append(i)
    else:
        right.append(i)
left = mergesort(left)
right = mergesort(right)
return merge(left,right)

def merge(left,right):
    sortedlist= []
    while left and right:
        if left[0]>right[0]:
            sortedlist.append(right[0])
            right.pop(0)
        else:
            sortedlist.append(left[0])
            left.pop(0)
    while left:
        sortedlist.append(left[0])
        left.pop(0)
    while right:
        sortedlist.append(right[0])
        right.pop(0)

    return sortedlist


print mergesort(lst)
```

The RunTimeError is: `maximum recursion depth exceeded`. Does anybody know the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing list values to list indices:

```
for i in array: # i is a list value
    if i <= len(array)/2: # len(array)/2 is a list index
```

Change this to `if i <= array[len(array)/2]:` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
lst = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

def mergesort(array):
    if len(array) == 1:
        return array
    left = []
    right = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if i < len(array)/2:
            left.append(array[i])
        else:
            right.append(array[i])



    left = mergesort(left)
    right = mergesort(right)
    return merge(left,right)

def merge(left,right):
    sortedlist= []
    while left and right:
        if left[0]>right[0]:
            sortedlist.append(right[0])
            right.pop(0)
        else:
            sortedlist.append(left[0])
            left.pop(0)
    while left:
        sortedlist.append(left[0])
        left.pop(0)
    while right:
        sortedlist.append(right[0])
        right.pop(0)

    return sortedlist


print mergesort(lst)
```

There was more than one error. You can compare it with your code. Hope it help.
Major error was in this line:

`if i < len(array)/2` which led `right` to be empty when `len(array)==2` which caused the error.